# Umbraco: scheduled tasks/publishing/keepalive not working

Tags: umbraco7, web-administration

I having problem on Umbraco 7.7.6 basically server call itself for tasks/publishing/keepalive details:

http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-5391

the problem is that server admin is not allowing external access to  internet from webserver  so that means http://(domain)/umbraco is not reachable and Umbraco is throwing following error in log file.

```
2017--06 13:42:45,673 [P3048/D15/T45] ERROR Umbraco.Web.Scheduling.KeepAlive – Failed (at “http://(domain)/umbraco”).
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Umbraco.Web.Scheduling.KeepAlive.<PerformRunAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
```

how can I mitigate the issue without giving outbound connection to internet from server?

Comment: On Umbraco 7, I've seen people suggest changing the `umbracoApplicationUrl`. If you've upgrade to 8.6+ by now, there's a way to specifically configure which URL is pinged: https://swimburger.net/blog/umbraco/introducing-umbracos-keepalive-ping-configuration